# Difference between vector<string> x; and vector<string> x(const string& s) {}

Tags: c++, function, parameters, declaration

I'm learning about vectors in `Accelerated C++` by Andrew Koenig and Barbara Moo. Can anyone explain the difference between these?

```
vector<string> x;
```

and

```
vector<string> x(const string& s) { ... }
```

Does the second one define a function `x` whose return type must be a vector and whose return value is stored somehow in x?

The exact code from the book starts like this:

```
map<string, vector<int> > xref(istream& in, vector<string> find_words(const string&) = split) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector<string> x;
```

This is a declaration of a variable named `x` of type `vector<string>`

```
vector<string> x(const string& s) { ... }
```

this is a function named `x` that takes 1 parameter of type `const string&` and returns a `vector<string>`

As you can see they are different beasts.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this function definition

```
map<string, vector<int> > xref(istream& in, 
                               vector<string> find_words(const string&) = split) 
{
    //...
}
```

confuses you.

The second parameter has the function type `vector<string>(const string&)` that is supplied with the default argument `split`.

Take into account that instead of the function type you could use a function pointer type. In any case the compiler adjusts a parameter that has a function type to a parameter that has a function pointer type.

Consider this demonstrative program. The both function declarations declare the same one function. In the first function declaration there is used a function type for the second parameter while in the second function declaration there is used a function pointer type for the same parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split( const string & );

map<string, vector<int> > xref( istream& in, 
                                vector<string> find_words(const string&) = split );

map<string, vector<int> > xref( istream& in, 
                                vector<string> ( *find_words )(const string&) );

int main() 
{

    return 0;
}
```

I only declared the function `split` without providing its definition because it is not required for this simple demonstrative program.

So you can call the function `xref` either with one argument and in this case the function will use the funcion `split` as the second argument by default. Or you could explicitly specify the second argument setting it to the name of your own written function.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that the latter is a function. The `vector` that function `x` creates however is not stored in a variable named `x`, rather the function itself is named `x`. You might do something like:

```
string my_str = "Hello world.";
// Call x to create my_vector:
vector<string> my_vector = x(my_str);
```