# What does this block define?

Tags: c++

I'm learning about vectors in `Accelerated C++` (which is C++ 98, not C++11) by Andrew Koenig and Barbara Moo. In this code...

```
map<string, vector<int>> xref(istream& in, vector<string> find_words(const string&) = split) { ...
```

...what is being defined in the block? `xref` or `find_words`? In my debugger, the call stack goes: `main() > xref() > split()`. `find_words` isn't defined elsewhere.

```
// find all the lines that refer to each word in the input
map<string, vector<int> > xref(istream& in, vector<string> find_words(const string&) = split) {
        string line;
        int line_number = 0;
        map<string, vector<int>> ret;

        // read the next line
        while (getline(in, line)) {
                ++line_number;

                // break the input line into words
                vector<string> words = find_words(line);

                // remember that each word occurs on the current line
                for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = words.begin();
                     it != words.end(); ++it)
                        ret[*it].push_back(line_number);
        }
        return ret;
}
```

Also, `split` looks like this:

```
vector<string> split(const string& s) { ... }
```

Comment: This could answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/47835838/5470596

Comment: `map<vector<T> >` is no longer needed, you can use `map<vector<T>>` now, fixed in C++11.

Comment: aren't you repeating your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387638/difference-between-vectorstring-x-and-vectorstring-xconst-string-s/49387713#49387713 ....

Comment: `find_words` _isn't defined elsewhere_ - but you can **see** where it's called, and you can see it really calls `split` on that line. So you know the line calling `find_words` really calls `split`. Maybe you haven't encountered function pointers before?

Comment: @bolov, in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387638/difference-between-vectorstring-x-and-vectorstring-xconst-string-s/49387713#49387713, I was trying to understand the theory (different definitions of vector), whereas in this question, I'm trying to understand the (book's) implementation of the second one: in a map.

Comment: @Useless, "function pointers" are indeed new to me. The book has not (yet) explained them.

Comment: A typedef for the function pointer type would sure make that code a bit more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
map<string, vector<int>> xref(
    istream& in, 
    vector<string> find_words(const string&) = split
) { /* ... */ }
```

This defines the function named `xref`. According to [Clockwise Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), `xref` is a function:

- taking as arguments:

  1. a `istream` reference (`istream& in`)
  2. a function: (`vector<string> find_words(const string&) = split`)

     - taking as argument:

       1. a `string` constant reference(`const string&`)
     - returning a `vector<string>`
     - whose default value is `split` (`= split`)
- and returning a `map<string, vector<int>>`

Answer (score 0):

`xref` is the function that is defined, `find_words` is one of its parameters (a function taking a `const string&` as parameter and returning a `vector<string>`) and `split` is the default value for that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`xref` is being defined in the code block and returns a map of a string and a vector of ints. It is taking in parameters of an `istream`by reference, a function that takes a string constant reference and returns a vector that the default value is split.